# How to build a selected list of branches and pull requests using Jenkins github organization folder plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to build limited set of Jenkins branches `master develop release* hotfix*` using Jenkins Github Organization Folder plugin.

The problem is that once I add the filter for the list of branches to build to `master develop release* hotfix*` Jenkins stops building PRs.

It does work as expected for these branches but I does not pull PRs made against them and this is mandatory as we want to be able to merge only code that was executed by Jenkins, but without having to include the source branches in the normal list of builds (we don't want to build each feature branch as they can get lots and lots of changes.)

Answer (score 1):

After two weeks and lots and lots of tests I finally raised a bug 
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36352

This seems to be a bug so far.